# Issues with download speeds in flareget

Tags: xubuntu, download-speed, download-manager

I have been using flareget for quite a few months and I'm normally very pleased with it. However, lately, when I try to download big files flareget starts off strong but then the download speed dwindles down and the download goes from about 20 mins to download to say over an hour to download and it just hangs there. I went to the support section of flareget.com and woefully there is hardly anything there so I decided to try my luck here. Any thoughts or suggestions? Btw, I am running Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: Are you sure is not a network problem? maybe the server where you're downloading have some new traffic rules. Have you tried with another download manager? Jdownloader maybe?

Comment: I'm sure it't not the website per se. I uninstalled flareget and installed downthemall and it seems to be working fine now and I can open the files. At least so far it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying uGet with the aria2 plugin.

Comment: Michael: Would you recommend uGet with the aria2 plugin over Downthemall?

Comment: yes because there is a lot more control you can doe with uGet as well as not required to run a browser at the same time. It also has advanced customization via Categories so almost every aspect of download settings can be created for multiple categories...such as multiple download folders, multiple speed controls and a lot more.

Comment: `uGet` 's speed awesome when increase max connections limit thanks @MichaelTunnell